# Indeterminate progressbar animation disappeared after adding indeterminateDrawable

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design

I need to add Radius the Horizontal progress bar with indeterminate.
but I've lost the cool indeterminate animation.

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_states"
        android:theme="@style/LinearProgress"/>
```

progressbar_states.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/greyish_brown"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
      android:top="1dp"
      android:bottom="1dp"
      android:left="1dp"
      android:right="1dp">
    <scale android:scaleWidth="100%" android:scaleGravity="center">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/neon_blue"/>
        </shape>
    </scale>
</item>
```

if i use android:scaleGravity="center"
the bar being filled from the center and if remove this line, the bar filled from the left side.
but how I make the bar to fill with the original android animation of indeterminate (material design).